# DELETE data from database if it is exists

Tags: php, html

I want to delete data from database if the same exists in database, but my coding is not working. if user input data is not matching then a error warning should be display.

HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="number" name="student_id_delete" placeholder="Enter Student ID"/>   
<input type="submit" name="sub_delete" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASSWORD_HOST','');
define('DATABASE','ubhs');

if(defined('HOST') && defined('USER') && defined('PASSWORD_HOST') && defined('DATABASE')){
$conn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD_HOST, DATABASE);
}else{
die(connection_failed.mysqli_connection_error());
}

$userinput = true;
$student_id_delete = $_POST['student_id_delete'];

if(isset($_POST['sub_delete'])){
  if(empty($student_id_delete)){
     $userErr1 = "Please enter student ID to be deleted";
     $userinput = false;
  }
  $sql = "SELECT FROM student_info WHERE id=$student_id_delete";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)<0){
    echo "student could not be found in database";
    $userinput = false;
    }
if($userinput==true){
       $sql = "DELETE FROM student_info WHERE id=$student_id_delete";
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        echo "Success";
        }else{
         echo "Couldn't deleted";
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work how? Btw there's no need to check if data exists. If it not exists - nothing will be removed.

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows($result)<0` - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Should be `mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1` or `mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0`

Comment: I'm guessing it should be `(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)` (it can't be less than 0)

Comment: Yes, but I have to display a error message if data does not matching.while running it a warning message is showing stating that mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given.

Comment: Besides, that code is full of potential disasters. Have a look at prepared queries, and shouldn't you just list students (either complete list or by search), and THEN select one to delete?

Comment: don't you think you should tell database what to select? `SELECT * FROM student_info`

Comment: The mysqli_affected_rows() function returns the number of affected rows in the previous SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE, or DELETE query. [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_affected_rows.asp)

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows` can only return `0` if it doesnt have any data

Comment: Guys, I have tried with all your suggestion but nothing is working

Comment: whats the output in `echo mysqli_num_rows($result)` ?

Comment: @Newbee Dev if data is matching with database then output is showing as 1 and if not then its showing 0

Comment: @phpLover then it should be `mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0`

Comment: @Newbee Dev yah...its working, thank you so much

Comment: @phpLover Since nobody said this; your code is open to an sql injection. Use a prepared statement; it's much safer over real_escape_string().

Comment: @Fred -ii I am using a function to prevent sql injection:                function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
} please let me know if it is safe?

Comment: @phpLover great, but do you mean "now" or "before" the answer was given below? If "before", then there's no use in using a prepared statement with `real_escape_string()`, which might even give undesired/unexpected results when using both together.

Comment: @Fred -ii Actually I forgot to mention  it "before" ;)

Comment: @phpLover that isn't a prepared statement function. This mysqli_ method http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php is. What you have now won't help you if/once you go live with this, or already are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below snippet :

HTML code :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="number" name="student_id_delete" placeholder="Enter Student ID"/>   
    <input type="submit" name="sub_delete" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

PHP code  :

```
<?php

    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','root');
    define('PASSWORD_HOST','');
    define('DATABASE','ubhs');

   if(defined('HOST') && defined('USER') && defined('PASSWORD_HOST') && defined('DATABASE'))
   {
        $conn = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD_HOST, DATABASE);
   }
   else
   {
       die(connection_failed.mysqli_connection_error());
   }

   $userinput = true;
   $student_id_delete = $_POST['student_id_delete'];

   if(isset($_POST['sub_delete']))
   {
       if(empty($student_id_delete))
       {
        $userErr1 = "Please enter student ID to be deleted";
        $userinput = false;
       }

       if($userinput==true)
       {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM student_info WHERE id=".mysqli_real_escape_string($student_id_delete); // sql injection prevention.
            mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            echo "Records deleted: ".mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
       }
   }
?>
```

OUTPUT : 
Records deleted: 1
Records deleted: 0

Comment: downvote because I have used mysqli_affected_rows, which supports only for older PHP version?

Comment: No, because of directly appending user input data to query. (SQL injection)

Comment: Aactually I have copied full code from question and focused only on explaining mysqli_affected_rows. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @RápliAndrás The point of SO is to provide help, not a fully working, tested and secured solution.

Comment: SO is what we make it. If something can be hacked, it will be hacked. Trivially insecure solutions are more harmful, but you can argue with me on meta...

Comment: @RápliAndrás I agree with Antoine. If you're going to downvote someone who isn't using a prepared statement or escaping their data in any way, it should be the OP and not the person who "answerered" the question. IMHO, you were out of line. Param Bhat did his best to help out. The mere mention of saying their code is open to an sql injection would have sufficed, again IMHO. It's not "our job" to do rewrites, but an added "bonus" if anything.